# (HTML+CSS) There is a Dot before my Instagram Logo

Tags: html, css

Im making my own Website and i inserted a picture of the Instagram Logo as a link to get to my Instagram, but on the Live server is the Instagram logo fully funktional BUT there is a Dot before the logo...

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <h1>
    How can i get in Touch with you?
  </h1>
  <p>
    You can Contact me on Instagram,Discord or via Email!
  </p>
  <li class="ContactLink" style="margin-left: 600px;">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dennisprivate04/"><img src="./img/Insta.png" alt="InstaLogo" height="50px" width="50px"></a>
</div>
```

[The logo with dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P72xb.png)

Comment: it has to do with that poor lonely `<li class="ContactLink" style="margin-left: 600px;">` :) Why do you use an li all alone ?

Comment: I fell so dumb right now ;D Thank you so much it was such an easy solution but my brain couldnt handle it

Comment: the `<li>` is an invalid HTML structure. it requires to be wrapped by either an `ul` or `ol`. Then the bullet can be removed by using `list-style-type: none;`

Answer (score 0):

The dot is caused by the `<li>` tag. You could just remove it and keep remaining of your instagram logo.

```
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dennisprivate04/"><img src="./img/Insta.png" alt="InstaLogo" height="50px" width="50px" style= "text-decoration: none;"></a>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Even though your anwser could solve the issue it is missing content. An anwser must always contain enough information on what the issue is and how you solved it. An anwser with a codeline has no ability to explain the issue and helping to reproduce the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didnt wanted to anwser this question as it is already anwsered in the comments. However as a "wrong" anwser and an insufficient anwser was given, I will anwser it to have a correct solution.

**The issue with your code:**
The dot you having is the `list-style bullet` you getting by having this line of code: `<li class="ContactLink" style="margin-left: 600px;">`. However this line of HTML code is invalid for 2 reasons. First you miss the closing tag `</li>`. Last but not least, a list must always be wrapped inside an ordered `<ol> ... </ol>` or undeorder list `<ul> ... </ul>`.

**How to fix it:**
First close your list tag by adding `</li>`. Then wrap the entire list inside an unordered list with `<ul> ... </ul>`. Give the class name to the `ul`. Use `list-style-type: none;` to remove the `list-style bullet`.

```css
.ContactLink {
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <h1>
    How can i get in Touch with you?
  </h1>
  <p>
    You can Contact me on Instagram,Discord or via Email!
  </p>
  <ul class="ContactLink">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dennisprivate04/">
        <img src="./img/Insta.png" alt="InstaLogo" height="50px" width="50px">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```